# WebClient query takes too long to complete, why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my C# code.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

while (true) {
   html = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\tSize: {0}", html.Length));
}
```

It takes around 9 seconds to get the first result. Then it takes around 3 seconds each.

When I do it with Java, it takes less than 1 second.

Why do you think it's so slow with C#? How can I improve it?

Comment: You have a problem in your network. This takes 0.16 sec on my machine: System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
string html = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Size: {0}", html.Length));
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);

Comment: Google will throttle your requests.

Comment: Same with @Marek, mine is fast < 1sec. Question, why use an infinite loop `while(true)`? When does it break?

Comment: It's very fast with Java though..
Alex R. It doesn't break. I have to manually stop.

Comment: @Jason: If they do that (i dont know if they do, but it is verry likely) it's probably to prevent getting spammed by testtools like these.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google API rate limiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662069/google-api-rate-limiting)

Comment: @Da9. Not sure about your case, but in my machine I also had to manually break.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You may have a problem with your network (as Mark comments).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the first Request always takes long using WebClient or WebRequest...
I do the same request with a Socket-Http class I build and it takes no time.

But after the 1st request it should go faster, good.

**Found a fix for the problem**

Try explicitly setting the proxy. If you don't have a proxy defined, the HttpRequest class will spend time searching for one. Once it has (or hasn't) found one, it will use that information for the life of the application, speeding up subsequent requests.

Set `request.Proxy = null;`