# Python Requests Module probleme

Tags: python

I created a script to get the URL links form Google results' page;  the script works fine however it runs for 3 times at maximum by your IP address after that Google blocks you.
I think it is because my header contains : `python-requests/2.3.0 CPython/2.7.2 Windows/7`. So I tried to change it by using headers and verify the result by using this [site](http://myhttp.info/).

This is my header :

```
headers = {
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0",
"Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Connection" : "keep-alive",}
```

But still Google detects me as a robot knowing that when I search with my browser everything works fine.

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google API rate limiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662069/google-api-rate-limiting)

Comment: Google is rather smart at detecting robots and very liberally with captcha challenges.

Comment: put a sleep in between your requests.  I work in a large office building behind a single IP.  Every now and then I get hit with a captcha because apparently we all need google at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with your script. Automated grabbing search results using a script violates every search engine’s terms of service. Search engines sniff out and block such access. You have to use one of Google's official APIs to get your data. Such as [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) or something similar.